# Return XML file from Web API

Tags: c#, beginner, xml, asp.net-core

I have a `HttpGet` method which returns XML file:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    await Task.Run(() => xmldoc.Load(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"\\user.config"));
    return Ok(xmlDoc);
}
```

Colleague said to me that this piece of code has smell and that I interrupted SOLID principles, but he did not explained to me what exact I do wrong.

Guys, please review my code and please explain me what I've done wrong.

Comment: Maybe ask your colleague what they mean exactly because just namedropping arbitrary comments like "you're violating SOLID" or "your code is not a GoF pattern" or something stupid like that is not constructive criticism.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen he goes to vacation and promises in 2 weeks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Dependency Inversion Priciple

The smell is that your code violates the [Dependency Inversion Priciple](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design#toc-dependency-inversion-principle) which reads

> Entities must depend on abstractions not on concretions. It states that the high level module must not depend on the low level module, but they should depend on abstractions.

This meas that your API depends on the `Load` method of the `XmlDocument` and not an abstraction such as a service like this one.

```
interface IXmlLoader
{
    XmlDocument Load(string path);
}
```

In consequence you cannot replace it for testing or use dependency injection and easily exchange it later if necessary. A *correct* implementation could look like this where you pass the dependency via the constructor. In some cases it might be also a property:

```
class XmlController
{
    private readonly IXmlLoader _xmlLoader;
    public XmlControler(IXmlLoader xmlLoader)
    {
        _xmlLoader = xmlLoader;
    }

    // Sometimes a property.
    // public IXmlLoader XmlLoader { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => _xmlLoader.Load(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"\\user.config"));
        return Ok(xmlDoc);
    }    

}
```

This is just an example. In your real code you should add null checks.

---

Another smaller smell is the hardcoded string `user.config` that you should at least configure via a property.

Comment: but how can  avoid hardcoded string `user.config` ?

Comment: @StepUp there are various options... it could be a property of the controler or a value in some kind of a settings provider/dictionary/thing...

Comment: Do you mean a variable in a  controller like that: `string xmlAddress = "user.config"`?

Comment: @StepUp it might be, if you pass it via the constructor or otherwise it is as hardcoded as the current value. At least a public property would be fine if you don't want to use anything _fancy_.

Comment: `it could be a property of the controler or a value in some kind of a settings provider/dictionary/thing` could you explain broader, please?

Comment: @StepUp my gut tells me you should have set the [tag:beginner] tag, without it people assume the _basics_ don't have to be mentioned ;-)

Comment: I've added this tag. Could you explain broader what you mean `value in some kind of a settings provider/dictionary/thing`?

Comment: @StepUp how about now?

Comment: Yeah, it is okay. `Another smaller smell is the hardcoded string user.config that you should at least configure via a property.` - could you show how I can do it? Is it okay to put property in controller?

Comment: @StepUp sure, why not? It has a bunch of its own properties already (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller_properties(v=vs.118).aspx) See the example above. I included a property for the service. The one for the config name would just be of type `string`.

Comment: I really cannot believe that I should create Interface and class to wrap up this just two lines of code. Is it really necessary just for two lines?

Comment: I disagree with the idea of wrapping every single built-in method in an interface. That is a "code smell" in itself and doesn't serve any purpose. If you go down that path, next you'll be writing `IStringConcatenator`... if you want to abstract something for testing maybe only abstract the filesystem access so you can redirect it to something else if you feel like it.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen if you do not intend to test anything (or apparently don't do it) then there is really no purpose in abstracting anything if you however are going to return a test XmlDocument for your unit tests then there is no way around.

Comment: @StepUp of course it's not necessary but you asked why it isn't SOLID so I showed you what is wrong. However if you want your application to be testable and for example use an xml file from an embeded resource inside a unit test project then you need an abstraction so that you can read it from somewhere else with a different service. This is how it works. It's up to you if you do it or not but I wouldn't allow your code into a production because it's practically untestable :-P

Comment: Now it's just two lines... but later... you'll probably save an xml... how would you like to verify that an API saves an xml? Do you want to check it on the harddrive? No, you provide a fake-service that receives your data to be saved to verfiy the operation really took place and the data is the data you expected.

Comment: Once you passed this initial _inconvenience_ it's much cooler to push a button and see the tests turn green instead of sitting there for an hour and pressing every damn button in order to check if you broke something ;-]

Comment: Oh, and one last thing. You usally implement such services only once, then you put in a library and you reuse it for the next project...

Comment: @StepUp if you would like to see a real example then see my question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166272/initializaing-and-running-console-application) where I heavily use DI for pretty much everything ;-) especially the method `InitializeComponents` (not that pretty yet - modules are necessary) and the constructor of the improved version.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say exactly what you're doing "wrong" without a more concrete example, but for starters, I would argue that XML is merely a representation of an object, so passing an `XMLDocument` into `Ok()` does seem like a smell.  At the very least, if you need to return an XML payload, use MVC formatters to serialize into XML from your response object (a Plain Old C# Object that you define).

(configured in Startup.cs):

```
mvcBuilder.AddMvcOptions(options => options.OutputFormatters.Add(
new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter(
    new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings() { NamespaceHandling = System.Xml.NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates, Async = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = false })));
```

See: [Introduction to formatting response data in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting)

Also, DI is the name of the game here, so you do want to inject some sort of meaningful service, which would own the work of whatever logic you need and returns the appropriate object.  I would never return that object directly to a consumer (encourages coupling), but that's purely a design decision based on the complexity involved and what you're trying to achieve.

Additionally, try your best to stay `async/await` all the way down. `await`ing a `Task.Run()` will not break anything, but you may find extreme corner cases in the future if you continue down that path, and it's always best to let the compiler work it's magic where you can delegate more to it.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing an XML document from disk just to later send it unchanged over the wire seems like a huge waste of CPU cycles. Why not simply send the file's content?

Comment: This is an interesing question but the answer is not so obvious I think and it depends... I could think of a few reasons why not to return a file directly (if it's not an image or other binary data): you might want to return it not only as xml but also a json or text later. You might want to modify the data on the way out and use a middleware that removes some sensitive information or transforms the document.